# Vue 3 - Always scroll to specific position on page when component appears

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a basic form component and that shows up once I click a button (router is not used). I want the scroll position of the form to scroll down a bit (ex. y-axis of 40) once the form shows up, but I'm not entirely sure how to achieve this. There are various examples about this, but I couldn't get any of them to work. Can someone kindly advice a solution for this, please? I also started using vue 3.

```
<template>
    <div class="appointment-wrapper" :class="[showForm ? 'appointment' : 'appointment-success']">
        // Scroll down to a certain point
        // ....
            <form @submit.prevent="validateForm" novalidate>
            // ....
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What about a watcher (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) that waits for the change, then using a ref on the form (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) to scroll it into view  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `window.scrollTo(0, 40)` if the condition is true after you clicked the button.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      showForm: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
     if (this.showForm) window.scrollTo(0, 400) // only demo value - use 40
  }
}).mount('#options-api')
```

```css
#options-api {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="options-api">
  <h1>hidden title</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to scroll to an element position

`document.getElementById(el).scrollIntoView();`

Or if you need to scroll by the axis

`window.scrollTo(0, 1000)`